# Can d3's key function handle a list element?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I have a CSV of fan fictions published over a time period. It looks something like:

```
id,published_date,characters
1,2017-01-01,'['Joe','Bob','Mary']'
2,2017-01-02,'['Mary']'
3,2017-01-02,'['Bob','Mary']'
```

I had pretty good success writing a key function by `published_date`, but now I want to see if I can write a key function for `characters`. So for the first row, Joe, Bob, and Mary would all be keys that have the value `2017-01-01`, then in the second row `2017-01-02` would be added to Mary's key. At the end I would like to do a `rollup` on `published_date` in order to get a count of number of fan fictions published about Mary on each date. I think the end data would look something like this:

```
{
 Bob: {2017-01-01: 1}, {2017-01-02: 1},
 Joe: {2017-01-01: 1},
 Mary: {2017-01-01: 1}, {2017-01-02: 2} 
}
```

So for `published_date`, my code looked like:

```
var dates = d3.nest()
              .key(function(d) { return parseDate(d.published_date); })
              .rollup(function(v) { return v.length; })
              .entries(csv_data);
```

And if my `characters` column were not a list, then I believe this would work:

```
var dates = d3.nest()
              .key(function(d) { return d.characters; }) // key by character
              .key(function(d) { return parseDate(d.published_date); })
              .rollup(function(v) { return v.length; })
              .entries(csv_data);
```

Is there a way I can change `key(function(d) { return d.characters; })` to actually create multiple keys?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unstack the data and you’ve got the right answer.

```
var csv = `id,published_date,characters
  1,2017-01-01,"[Joe,Bob,Mary]"
  2,2017-01-02,"[Mary]"
  3,2017-01-02,"[Bob,Mary]"`;

var csvData = d3.csvParse(csv, function(r) {
  return {
    id: +r.id,
    publishedDate: new Date(r.published_date),
    characters: r.characters.slice(1,-1).split(",")
  };
});

var data = [];
csvData.forEach(function(r) {
  r.characters.forEach(function(c) {
    data.push({
      id: r.id,
      publishedDate: r.publishedDate,
      character: c
    });
  });
});
```

Now this should work the way you want it to.

```
var nested = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.character; })
  .key(function(d) { return d.publishedDate; })
  .rollup(function(v) { return v.length })
  .entries(data);
```